# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android

I'm developing this simple app in the form of quiz where user gets question and 4 options. These questions are being fetched from SQLite DB. In my succ.java activity i display the question as well as fetch the next question on click of next button.

Now when running it on emulator, if i dont select any of the 4 radio buttons my app ultimately stops and i have to force close. To deal with this i thought of checking in my succ.java page that if neither of the options ae selected fetch the question from db with same question id and if either one i selected fetch the question with next question id.

But it still won't work , i have tried everything possible that i could have done. I'm attaching my succ.java. and also the logcat along.

**succ.java**

```
public class succ extends Activity {
private static String[] response = new String[10];

RadioButton op1,op2,op3,op4;

private int token_page;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainquespage);



    int qno=0;
     String ques="";
     String ans1="";
     String ans2="";
     String ans3="";
     String ans4="";
     //int token=0;
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    //token=extras.getInt("SESS_ID");
     ques=extras.getString("KEY_QUES");
     ans1=extras.getString("KEY_ANS1");
     ans2=extras.getString("KEY_ANS2");
     ans3=extras.getString("KEY_ANS3");
     ans4=extras.getString("KEY_ANS4");
     qno=extras.getInt("KEY_ID");
     token_page=qno+1;
     TextView quesnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quesIDTEXT);
     quesnumber.setText("QUESTION: "+ qno );
     TextView quescont=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quesContText);
     quescont.setText(ques);
     TextView opt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op1Text);
     opt1.setText(ans1);
     TextView opt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op2Text);
     opt2.setText(ans2);
     TextView opt3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op3Text);
     opt3.setText(ans3);
     TextView opt4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op4Text);
     opt4.setText(ans4);

}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    op1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op1Text);
    op2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op2Text);
    op3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op3Text);
    op4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op4Text);

    if(op1.isChecked())
    {
        response[token_page-2]=op1.getText().toString();
    }
    else if(op2.isChecked()){
        response[token_page-2]=op2.getText().toString();
    }
    else if(op3.isChecked()){
        response[token_page-2]=op3.getText().toString();
    }
    else if(op4.isChecked()){
        response[token_page-2]=op4.getText().toString();
    }
    else
        response[token_page-2]="";

  }
public void nextClick(View view)
{
    final Context context=this;
    Question question=new Question();
    MyAdapter questionAdapter=new MyAdapter(this);

            if(token_page!=11)
            {   
            questionAdapter.open();
    if(op1.isChecked()||op2.isChecked()||op3.isChecked()||op4.isChecked())
    {
        question=questionAdapter.showQues(token_page);
    }
    else
    {
        question=questionAdapter.showQues(token_page-1);
    }
//please note when i'm just writing: question=questionAdapter.showQues(token_page) //without checking for the selection of radio buttons i get the error i the end after the //last question is answered but when i'm checking it here and using if els then am getting //an error on the same screen. i'm stuck on this since forever. HELP !!

     questionAdapter.close();

        int qno;
     String ques;
     String ans1;
     String ans2;
     String ans3;
     String ans4;
     qno=question.getQno();
     ques=question.getQues();
     ans1=question.getAns1();
     ans2=question.getAns2();
     ans3=question.getAns3();
     ans4=question.getAns4();

        Intent intent=new Intent(context, succ.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_ID", qno);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_QUES",ques);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS1",ans1);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS2",ans2);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS3",ans3);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS4",ans4);

            startActivity(intent);

    }//token_page
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "FINISHED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("ARRAY", response);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, result.class);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
  06-26 11:26:48.401: D/opendb(357): EXIST
06-26 11:26:52.321: W/KeyCharacterMap(357): No keyboard for id 0
06-26 11:26:52.321: W/KeyCharacterMap(357): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-26 11:26:53.781: D/dalvikvm(357): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 122K, 51% free 2699K/5447K, external 2128K/2137K, paused 63ms
06-26 11:26:59.923: W/KeyCharacterMap(357): No keyboard for id 0
06-26 11:26:59.923: W/KeyCharacterMap(357): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-26 11:29:49.512: D/opendb(478): EXIST
06-26 11:29:58.981: D/AndroidRuntime(478): Shutting down VM
06-26 11:29:58.981: W/dalvikvm(478): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  ... 11 more
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at my.pkg.newquiz.succ.nextClick(succ.java:98)
06-26 11:29:59.011: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  ... 14 more
06-26 11:30:02.821: I/Process(478): Sending signal. PID: 478 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Which one is line number 98 in your succ.java file?

Comment: if(op1.isChecked()||op2.isChecked()||op3.isChecked()||op4.isChecked())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i dont select any of the 4 radio buttons my app ultimately stops
>   and i have to force close.

It is happening as expected according to your code.

The biggest mistake you are doing is you are initializing your radio buttons when you check them.below is a snippet you have written.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    op1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op1Text);
    op2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op2Text);
    op3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op3Text);
    op4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op4Text);
```

So if the scenario is if you dont select any of radio buttons neither will be initialized and then if click next button you will obviously get NPE.

```
if(op1.isChecked()||op2.isChecked()||op3.isChecked()||op4.isChecked())
    {
        question=questionAdapter.showQues(token_page);
    }
```

So solution is Initialize all your radio buttons in onCreate.

Below is modified snippet.

```
public class succ extends Activity {
private static String[] response = new String[10];

RadioButton op1,op2,op3,op4;

private int token_page;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainquespage);

    op1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op1Text);
    op2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op2Text);
    op3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op3Text);
    op4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.op4Text); 


    int qno=0;
     String ques="";
     String ans1="";
     String ans2="";
     String ans3="";
     String ans4="";
     //int token=0;
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    //token=extras.getInt("SESS_ID");
     ques=extras.getString("KEY_QUES");
     ans1=extras.getString("KEY_ANS1");
     ans2=extras.getString("KEY_ANS2");
     ans3=extras.getString("KEY_ANS3");
     ans4=extras.getString("KEY_ANS4");
     qno=extras.getInt("KEY_ID");
     token_page=qno+1;
     TextView quesnumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quesIDTEXT);
     quesnumber.setText("QUESTION: "+ qno );
     TextView quescont=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.quesContText);
     quescont.setText(ques);
     TextView opt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op1Text);
     opt1.setText(ans1);
     TextView opt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op2Text);
     opt2.setText(ans2);
     TextView opt3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op3Text);
     opt3.setText(ans3);
     TextView opt4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.op4Text);
     opt4.setText(ans4);


}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {



    if(op1.isChecked())
    {
        response[token_page-2]=op1.getText().toString();
    }
    else if(op2.isChecked()){
        response[token_page-2]=op2.getText().toString();
    }
    else if(op3.isChecked()){
        response[token_page-2]=op3.getText().toString();
    }
    else if(op4.isChecked()){
        response[token_page-2]=op4.getText().toString();
    }
    else
        response[token_page-2]="";

  }
public void nextClick(View view)
{
    final Context context=this;
    Question question=new Question();
    MyAdapter questionAdapter=new MyAdapter(this);

            if(token_page!=11)
            {   
            questionAdapter.open();
    if(op1.isChecked()||op2.isChecked()||op3.isChecked()||op4.isChecked())
    {
        question=questionAdapter.showQues(token_page);
    }
    else
    {
        question=questionAdapter.showQues(token_page-1);
    }
//please note when i'm just writing: question=questionAdapter.showQues(token_page) //without checking for the selection of radio buttons i get the error i the end after the //last question is answered but when i'm checking it here and using if els then am getting //an error on the same screen. i'm stuck on this since forever. HELP !!

     questionAdapter.close();

        int qno;
     String ques;
     String ans1;
     String ans2;
     String ans3;
     String ans4;
     qno=question.getQno();
     ques=question.getQues();
     ans1=question.getAns1();
     ans2=question.getAns2();
     ans3=question.getAns3();
     ans4=question.getAns4();

        Intent intent=new Intent(context, succ.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_ID", qno);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_QUES",ques);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS1",ans1);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS2",ans2);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS3",ans3);
         intent.putExtra("KEY_ANS4",ans4);

            startActivity(intent);

    }//token_page
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "FINISHED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("ARRAY", response);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, result.class);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wooaa.. i got through. Thankss ! i have been on this since days now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1481789 whenever NPE occurs it is always related to uninitialized stuff most of the time.

Comment: thanks i have just started developing with java and android. i'll keep this in mind. thanks a bunch.